# knitr spin: large plots side by side

Tags: r, knitr

I want to display 2 plots side by side using spin()
If I have

```
#' ### 4.2. Display
#+ fig.show='hold', fig.width=5, fig.height=5
plot(1:10,1:10, type="p", main="Left")
plot(1:10,1:10, type="p", main="Right")

#' fin
```

run spin() and then click html preview for the *.md file in RStudio, I get what I want. But if I try
to increase the size of the plots, then they are vertically arranged:

```
#' ### 4.2. Display
#+ fig.show='hold', fig.width=8, fig.height=8
plot(1:10,1:10, type="p", main="Left")
plot(1:10,1:10, type="p", main="Right")

#' fin
```

I thought I could just increase out.width, but this seem to affect the
resolution rather than the actual size.
Is there a way to increase the width of the html page so that both
plots of 8in can be arranged size by size?

Thanks

Comment: if you want them horizontally, why not just use `par(mfrow = c(1,2))`?

Comment: That is not a general solution. I'm using a base plot just for the example. Anyway, the bottom problem is that I do not understand the combined behaviour of fig.width and/or fig.height with out.width. For example, if I use par(mfrow=c(1,2)) and set fig.width and fig.height to 12 leaving out.width at its default value, I get 2 tiny plots.

Comment: I meant  out.width=300, dont know if that's the default.

Comment: what css are you using

Comment: Whatever comes by default for knitr with RStudio. How can I check that?

Comment: I was just thinking you could change the body width via css because when you increase the size of the image, they can no longer fit within the width of the body. I'm not sure the correct way to insert html in `spin` (in .rmd, you can write like regular text), but this worked for me `#+ results='asis', echo=FALSE
cat('<style>body {max-width: 150em;}</style>')` the current max width you have is probably 70 or so. you can increase to whatever you like although it does increase the width of other things as well. not optimal and hacky, but it may be an option